# What is the relationship between SelectListItem and SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

From MSDN, I could not see any relationships. Also, if I assign IEnumberable when creating a new instance of SelectList, it doesn't populate the options for me either. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relation is that `SelectList` implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which translated to a *non technical language* means that `SelectList` is a collection of `SelectListItem` or if you prefer `SelectList` is composed of multiple `SelectListItem`s.